Trouble verifying Google token in Flask application
I'm developing a web application using Flask for the backend and React for the frontend, integrating Google Sign-In using OAuth2. I have a /verify-google-token endpoint in Flask to handle POST requests containing the Google token sent from the frontend using Axios.
Issue:
When I attempt to verify the Google token on the backend, I consistently receive a 400 (BAD REQUEST) error. The specific error messages in the console are:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Error verifying Google token: AxiosError

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call. (Repeated twice)


Backend Route Code:
Here's the relevant code snippet of my Flask backend:
@app.route('/verify-google-token', methods=['POST'])
def verify_google_token():
    token = request.json.get('token')
    if not token:
        return jsonify({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Token is missing'}), 400

    try:
        # Verify the Google token
        url = f"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token={token}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad responses

        token_info = response.json()

        # Extract user information from the verified token
        google_id = token_info.get('user_id')
        email = token_info.get('email')
        name = token_info.get('name')

        # Check if the user already exists in the database
        collection = db['users']
        existing_user = collection.find_one({'google_id': google_id})

        if existing_user:
            return jsonify({
                'status': 'success',
                'message': 'User already exists',
                'user_id': str(existing_user['_id']),
                'email': existing_user['email']
            }), 200

        # Create a new user document in MongoDB
        new_user = {
            'google_id': google_id,
            'email': email,
            'name': name,
            'is_online': False,
            'last_seen': None
        }
        result = collection.insert_one(new_user)

        return jsonify({
            'status': 'success',
            'message': 'User added to database',
            'user_id': str(result.inserted_id),
            'email': email
        }), 201


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Unexpected error occurred'}), 500

My frontend:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';

const Login = () => {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/verify-google-token`, { token: response.tokenId })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const { user_id, email, picture } = response.data;
                    setProfile({ user_id, email, picture });
                } else {
                    setErrorMessage('Google Sign-In failed. Please try again.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error verifying Google token:', error);
                setErrorMessage('Google Sign-In failed. Please try again.');
            });
    };

    const handleLogout = () => {
        setProfile(null); // Clear profile state on logout
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            {profile ? (
                <div>
                    <img src={profile.picture} alt="user profile" />
                    <p>User ID: {profile.user_id}</p>
                    <p>Email: {profile.email}</p>
                    <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <GoogleLogin
                    clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                    buttonText="Login with Google"
                    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                    onFailure={responseGoogle}
                    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                />
            )}
            {errorMessage && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errorMessage}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

**
Additional Context:**

I'm using react-google-login on the frontend to obtain the Google token and Axios to send it to the backend.

Environment variables (REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET) are properly configured.

I've reviewed similar issues on Stack Overflow and tried various solutions, including validating the Google token using https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token={token}, as recommended by Google's documentation.


Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on resolving the 400 (BAD REQUEST) error when verifying the Google token on the Flask backend. Specifically, I'd like to understand why the token verification is failing and how to correct it. Any insights, troubleshooting steps, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
